# Where can I go for opinions and idea generation for TRPGs?

Tags: dnd-5e, new-gm

I am newer to DMing. I started playing D&D 5e with a bunch of friends about a year ago and volunteered to be DM since I like keeping up with rules, inundating myself in all the books, etc. However, I know almost no one outside of my group who plays, and my only experience in the game is, well, in my game. I have been looking for a site where I could post to try to generate ideas, or get help out of plot-holes before the next game session (we play every week). No where seems to work. Youtubers with great ideas have large audiences pelting them with questions, and if you're not a patreon, they may answer yours within the next month or so (always good answers, and I get why they have to prioritise questions, etc). Next I tried the Nerdarchy forum, but it can take weeks to get a reply if you ever get one. Next I tried this site. My post was locked down as having an opinion based-answer, and after looking at other questions, I understand why, so I apologise for posting the wrong kind of question for this site. However, I am wondering where I can go to ask for ideas and opinions for D&D and hope to hear back in less than a week of posting. Hopefully this does not count as opinion based. If it does, I apologise as well. I am new to the hobby, inexperienced with this site, and am simply looking for the right resources to help me.

Comment: The following Meta discussion might be interesting for you: [I've been told my question is better suited to a forum, but where should I go?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5449/ive-been-told-my-question-is-better-suited-to-a-forum-but-where-should-i-go)

Comment: I will note that Our Very Own (TM) [chat] is one of the forums linked above, and you're welcome there any time. Just-about every day there's *some* discussion of "hey, I'm working on this but need some [ideas|refinement|critical eyes]."